# Talend increment counter

Tags: counter, talend

I'm making a ETL in Talend that add data in a table.

The table is for a old system and the primary key is not auto-incremental.
So I have to get the maximum id plus one every time that I insert a value in the table.

I'm trying to use a var in the Expression Builder:

- first I save the max and set in a context variable
- then in the Expression Builder:

  ```
  Context.Max += 1
  ```

The problem is that every time I get the same id, I need to save the sum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found what was looking for:

```
Numeric.sequence("var2", Context.Max, 1)
```

This increment by 1 the `Context.Max` and save it in `"var2"`.

Comment: Syntax: Numeric.sequence("Parameter name", start value, increment value)